# English translation of Kepler's "Nova stereometria doliorum vinariorum"

Tags: calculus, geometry, math-history

Is there a freely available English translation of Kepler's "Nova stereometria doliorum vinariorum"? Google has managed to come up empty, but I have trouble imagining such a seemingly historic and important work wouldn't have an English translation at this point.

Comment: I looked around, presumably you already found the [Latin scan](http://posner.library.cmu.edu/Posner/books/pages.cgi?call=520_K38PN&layout=vol0/part0/copy0) and [this discussion](https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/kepler-the-volume-of-a-wine-barrel-introduction)